# Cofactor matrix of the surface gradient

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

What is the cofactor matrix of
$$
\nabla_s\boldsymbol r=\nabla\boldsymbol r-\boldsymbol n\left(\boldsymbol n\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol r\right),
$$
if $\boldsymbol r:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^3$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, $S=\partial\Omega$?

I guess it is
$$
\operatorname{cof}\nabla_s\boldsymbol r=\left(\begin{array}{c c c} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x_2}-\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x_1} \end{array}\right),
$$
but I am not sure if
$$
\nabla_s\boldsymbol r=\left(\begin{array}{c c c} \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x_1} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x_1} & 0 \\ \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x_2} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x_2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).
$$

Comment: I will help you a little. I think you are confusing the (standard/usual) coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and say special local coordinates which are adapted to $S$.

Comment: So, as I understand, the form of $\nabla_s\boldsymbol r$ is wrong.

Comment: I got your hint. So, it must be
$$
\nabla_s\boldsymbol r=\left(\begin{array}{c c c} \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x_1^s} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x_1^s} & 0 \\ \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x_2^s} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x_2^s} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).
$$
$x_1^s$ and $x_2^s$ are the local coordinates on $S$.

Comment: Ok. I will try my best to help out. If $\mathbf{r}$ is defined only on the surface $S$, then it only makes sense to differentiate with respect to say $x$, $y$, which are local coordinates on $S$. But then you can always extend the coordinates $x$ and $y$ and complete them locally to some local coordinates $x$, $y$, $z$ in an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that the surface $S$ is given by say $z=0$ (this is called the straightening lemma).

Comment: Actually, $\boldsymbol r$ is defined in some 3D domain $\Omega$, the boundary of which is $S$.

Comment: Ahhh. That changes everything. Ok I will think a bit, and write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so $\mathbf{r}$ can be thought of as a vector field on $\Omega$, and $\nabla_s$ is then the Levi-Civita connection of the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ restricted to $S$. One can always find local coordinates $x$, $y$, $z$, such that the surface $S$ is described locally by $z = 0$, and $\Omega$ is described locally by $z \geq 0$.

Then

$\nabla_s\boldsymbol r=\left(\begin{array}{c c c} \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial x} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial y} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial z} \\ \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial x} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial y} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial r_2}{\partial z} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$.

Now you can easily compute the cofactor matrix. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: If $S$ is a surface, then how to treat $z$? And since the third row is 0, then it lies into the tangent plane, right?

Comment: Well, $\nabla_s r$ along a specific direction $v$ is the orthogonal projection onto the tangent bundle of $S$ of $\nabla r$ along $v$. You can differentiate along the $z$ direction since $r$ is defined on $\Omega$, and then orthogonally project onto the tangent bundle of $S$. If $S$ is locally defined by say $f(x,y,z) = 0$ for some smooth function $f$, then I can adapt my answer to that case, if you want.